# Eslint issue with running script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have a script **lint** that runs eslint check under the **src** folder

And checks for files with extenstions: js,tsx,ts

But when I run next script I got error that pattern is not good:

Script:

```
"lint": "eslint '**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js}'",
```

Error after run **yarn lint**

```
No files matching the pattern "**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js}" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with a pattern?

Comment: Try to change single quotes to escaped double quotes like this : "lint": "eslint \"**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\""

Comment: still not, it's weird. 
This is React app that I migrate to Nx workspace, and after that, this script stopped working...

Comment: Probably it's because of the additional asterisks at the start of the pattern,

Answer (score 0):

what helped me was removing the quotes in the pattern such than my final script was `"lint:fix": "eslint --fix **/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below command as it's working for me

```
"lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\" \"src/**/*.tsx\" \"src/**/*.js\" ",
```

Answer (score 0):

extra asterisk in the command

from:

```
'**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js}'
```

to:

```
'src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js}'
```